# Vertical Swipe Issue in View Pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe, gesture

I am using view pager and **the vertical swipe is not working**, I searched a lot but to no avail I find this solution but this isn't working properly too, the solution is to block the click listener on the text view link this

```
details.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                details.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

but then i can't swipe the view pages on the text view, i then tried to detect the **gesture using gesture detector on my fragment** and on left/right swipe i change the fragment with the animation, this trick works fine but the problem is **the look of animation isn't as the view pager** gives. I did find the solution and i am sharing it to help  other better answers is appreciated too.

Comment: Do you want ViewPager to scroll vertically or it's content or maybe the parent of the ViewPager? Do you want swipe gesture to work in both directions for different views?

Comment: i want the page to swipe in both directions the vertical swipe of my xml layout and the view pager swipe too and i solved it using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i did and hope it help you guys, thanks if it doesn't let me know and if you have any better idea please share so that we can improve.

// write this code in activity or fragmentActivity oncreate note that i am passing the data in internt for my use please skip that if u dont want

```
Intent newsFrag = new Intent(mContext, PageViewActivity.class);
newsFrag.putExtra("xyz", getArguments().getString("xyz"));
newsFrag.putExtra("abc", abc);
startActivity(newsFrag);
```

in view pager activity i did this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class PageViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
List<Fragment> fragments;
RSSFeed feed;
String xyz;
int pos;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_view);
    xyz= getIntent().getExtras().getString("xyx");
    abc = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("abc");

    feed = LocalDatabaseManager.getInstance(this).fetchOnCategory(xyz);

    fragments = getFragments();

    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(pos - 1);
}

private List<Fragment> getFragments() {

    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    for (int i = 0; i < feed.getItemCount(); i++) {
        MyFragmentNews myfrag = new MyFragmentNews();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("abc", abc- 1);
        bundle.putString("xyz", xyz);
        myfrag.setArguments(bundle);

        myfrag.newInstance(feed.getItem(i));
        fList.add(myfrag);
    }
    return fList;
  }
}
```

this is how i make fragments

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyFragmentNews extends Fragment {
RSSItem rssItem;
ImageButton bookmark;
private RelativeLayout progressLoader;
private FrameLayout theRoot;

public MyFragmentNews newInstance(RSSItem newsItem) {
    MyFragmentNews f = new MyFragmentNews();
    rssItem = newsItem;
    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_details, container, false);

    TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newHeading);
    heading.setText(AppUtils.cleanSymbols(Html.fromHtml(rssItem.getTitle()).toString()));


    return view;
}
```

}

and this is the link that helped me http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html

if someone what to do it with gesture dector i can post that code too, hope it helps thanks